# How to implement abstract properties in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, abstract

How do I make `$myVar` abstract in `ParentClass`?

```
<?php
abstract class ParentClass
{
    public $myVar;  //Make this abstract

    abstract public function get();

    public function someMethod() {}
}

class childClass extends ParentClass
{
    public $myVar = 123;

    public function get(){}

    public function someOtherMethod() {}
}
```

Comment: @JohnConde.  Yea, I saw that post, but didn't know it was still valid in PHP 7

Comment: Nothing can change as far as this is concerned. It's just a fundemental of how it work

Comment: @JohnConde  Thank you John.  A bit off topic, but is such a concept implemented in other languages?

Comment: It can't be as explained by the answer in the duplicate question.